# preventing form to be submitted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to check on form submit that certain condition is satisfied before submitting the form

```
function checkConditions(e){
    if ($('#someId').val() == '') {
       console.log('value of #someId is empty');        
       e.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
}
$('form').submit(function (e) {            
     checkConditions(e);    
});
```

on form submit I'm getting print inside console that value is empty but form is sumbitted eitherway. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: <s>That should work.</s> [That works.](http://jsfiddle.net/ezvwg42b/)

Comment: use e.preventDefault();

Comment: @Yuri: Look again at the question.

Comment: Why not use the built in features of MVC and apply the `[Required]` attribute to the property and enable client side validation?

Comment: @StephenMuecke :) I'm aware of that but I have my own reasons for doing this way.

Comment: maybe you need $.trim($('#someId').val()) == ''

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef: That would make sense, but the OP says that he sees the console.log...

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right .. but for me sometimes I can't find a noticed deference between empty and spaces in console.log or alert .cause of that I said about trim to avoid right and left whitespaces . anyway trim will help him somewhere :-) ..

Comment: @user1765862: From the button's tooltip: "...is is unclear or not useful." The code in the question works, as was pointed out (and proven) half an hour ago. So the question cannot be answered as it currently stands. Eventually, not having been clarified or removed, it will attract down- and close-votes. Fortunately, Joseph was good enough to remove his incorrect (but upvoted) answer, so you can delete the question if you can't add more detail to it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is right, I was in the understanding that a return would work, but in effect it's doing the same. It is something that I would love to know how it got solved in the end though.

Comment: Are you using jQuery mobile? If yes, try to add `data-ajax="false"` in your `<form>`

Comment: @Joseph: Congrats on your new [disciplined badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined). You are one of an elite few who are disciplined enough to do the correct thing, nice one!

Comment: Sorry I was a bit stubborn there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkConditions(){
    if ($('#someId').val() == '') {
       console.log('value of #someId is empty'); 
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
$('form').submit(function (e) {            
     if(!checkConditions()){
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     }
});
```